# List doesn't show up on front end

Tags: java, html, spring

I'm working on a problem where I have a program to manage course. I have to create a lesson with a teacher & student, although when I have added a lesson to the DB & want it to show up on the frontend website, although it's not happening.

Student & Teacher are working fine, after adding a new Student/Teacher it redirects to the main page & the new list is available.

Data is visible in SQL Workbench & I can see the records adding.

Could you advise why the list is not showing up in front end?

LessonController class:

```java
@Controller
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@RequestMapping("/lessons")
public class LessonController {

    private final LessonService lessonService;
    private final TeacherService teacherService;
    private final StudentService studentService;
    
    @GetMapping
    public String getLessonList(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("lessons",lessonService.findAll());
        return "lesson/list";
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/create")
    public String getLessonCreateForm(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("teachers", teacherService.findAll());
        model.addAttribute("students", studentService.findAll());
        return "lesson/form";
    }
    
    @PostMapping("/create")
    public String createLesson(Lesson lesson,
                               @RequestParam("studentId") int studentId,
                               @RequestParam("teacherId") int teacherId) {
        lessonService.save(lesson,studentId,teacherId);
        return "redirect:/lessons";
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Lekcje</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Lekcje</h1>
</br>

<p2><a href="/lessons/create">dodaj</a></p2>
</br>
</br>

<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Student</th>
        <th>Nauczyciel</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr th:each="lesson : ${lesson}">
        <td th:text="${lesson.id}"></td>
        <td th:text="${student.firstName} + ' ' + ${student.lastName}"></td>
        <td th:text="${teacher.firstName} + ' ' + ${teacher.lastName}"></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the desired output for the lessons front end is to display the lessons from the DB. Here is a screenshot of the students front end:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to add URL to `@GetMapping` annotation above `getLessonList` method, I believe it should be `@GetMapping("lesson/list")` or `@GetMapping("lessons")`

Comment: I have tried your advise & after refreshing the webpage I get this error:

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Mon Feb 13 22:06:41 CET 2023
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available